# getting data from database with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hey guys I know this was asked a lot of times and this is the first time I get a problem with it, I need to get data from database but its not working and there's no error in console. I can't get it to work for some reason, I have everything setup right, my ajax is good I guess?

Here's my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label> Event</label>
    <?php
    $event = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM event');
    $event->execute();
    $eventrows = $event->fetchAll();
    ?>
    <select class="form-control" id="event" name="event_id">
        <?php
        foreach ($eventrows AS $eventrow) {
        ?>
        <option
        value="<?php echo $eventrow['EventID']; ?>"><?php echo $eventrow['EventName']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label> Level</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="level" name="level_id">
    </select>
</div>
```

My Ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#event').change(function() {
    var event_id = $(this).children(":selected").val();
    $.post("get_level.php", {
      event_id: event_id
    }, function(data, status) {
      console.log(status);
      if (status == 'success') {

        var loopdata = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#level').html('')
        $.each(loopdata, function(i, item) {
          $('#level').append("<option value='" + loopdata[i].LevelID + "'>" + loopdata[i].LevelName + "</option>");
        });
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

get_level.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

$reg = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Level WHERE EventID = '".$_POST['event_id']."'");
$reg->execute(array());
$allreg=$reg->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($allreg);  // pass array in json_encode
?>
```

Comment: What error you are getting in developer's console or check in Network tab of developer console of your browser...

Comment: Does the console show any errors? Is PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: Please add example response from `get_level.php`.

Comment: You really need to add some explanation here.  Don't just dump code and hope we know what happened

Comment: you haven't added closing double quotes for id `<select class="form-control" id="level name="level_id">`

Comment: i dont get any error in the console thats the thing

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli / PDO. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL like that.

Comment: @Mynameisjeff have read my comment? First resolve your syntax of select tag then let us know if error remains

Comment: "not working" is not an error message or problem statement. Have you verified that the ajax call actually runs? (check in your browser's network tab). What HTTP response code do you get back from it? Is there anything in the response body? Does your query work if you run it in SQL directly? One specific thing to check - is the EventID column in your DB an int or a varchar (string)? Because your SQL is sending the ID in the WHERE clause as a string. If EventID column is int then you'll never get any rows returned because a string value won't match to an int, even if it looks like a number.

Comment: @JigarShah  that was a copy error i dont have that error in my code

Comment: Those are all basic debugging steps you can take even before you ask a question. Narrow down the problem to the specific place in the flow where things start to go wrong. P.S. Any problem with the datatype in the DB query could be avoided entirely anyway by using parameterised queries - it's a side benefit.

Comment: @ADyson  yeah i checked all of that :)

Comment: @Mynameisjeff Ok...and, the results? If you look carefully at my questions, I asked for specifics, not for you to say "yeah it's ok", because maybe you missed some detail, since you're having a problem.

Comment: @ADyson i rechecked i notice that im sending the wrong variable to the  get_level page but it didnt fix the problem thanks for reminding me to check my code again dawg

Comment: ok...so now we know we're sending the right variable value. But still a problem. Onto the next part: Have you verified the query is successful? You still haven't answered my question about data types, for instance, or what HTTP response you get. Until you do I can't be sure you've checked it correctly, or at all. If you just answer all the questions straight off, we'll get there a lot quicker.

Comment: i started getting Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at tickets-add.php:249 in the consolelog @ADyson

Comment: that means you haven't included jQuery in your page. So chances are your ajax call is not even running, because $.ajax is a jQuery function, as is most of the other code on your page.

Comment: i have included im running bootstrap and bootstrap required jQuery @ADyson

Comment: Bootstrap does not always require jQuery, depending how you use it. But it's irrelevant - your ajax code 100% requires jQuery, with or without bootstrap. You say you've included it, but that error message is telling you you haven't. Add a valid reference to jQuery in your page, and then see what result you get. And if it's still not fully working, then please provide the answers to my other questions from half an hour ago. Like I said, if you provide them all in one go we can find the problem much faster than going back-and-forth like this with one small thing at a time.

Comment: P.S. Instead of just stating that you've done things and assuming it works, it's a good idea to actually verify it before continuing. You said you'd included jQuery but clearly you haven't, or at least not properly. You'll find programming is a long hard road if you don't do basic tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem in the code but the placement of the code, the reason the ajax didn't work that it should be the last thing in the page after the include of the footer coz the footer has the jQuery includes

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#event').change(function() {
    var event_id = $(this).val();
    $.post("get_level.php", {
        event_id: event_id
      }, 'json')
      .done(function(loopdata) {
        $('#level').html('')
        $.each(loopdata, function(i, item) {
          $('#level').append("<option value='" + item.LevelID + "'>" + item.LevelName + "</option>");
        });
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: because? Add an explanation, just a dump of code is no use to anyone, we don't know what you changed, or, more importantly, why.